# Annotate with a static date - Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I'm trying to annotate a queryset with a static date in Django.

With an integer (instead of a date) it works:

```
from django.db.models import Value, IntegerField

cars= Car.objects.all().annotate(sales=Value(0, IntegerField()))
```

How can I make it works with date??

```
from django.db.models import Value, DateField

cars= Car.objects.all().annotate(mydate=Value('2019-01-01', DateField()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/)

```
cars= Car.objects.annotate(sales=Cast(Value('20190101'), output_field=DateField()))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!